# Correct way to use EmberJS + RequireJS with Mixins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, ember.js, requirejs

For a while now I've been trying to get started using EmberJS, with RequireJS as a dependency loader via this project on Github: https://github.com/fernandogmar/Emberjs-RequireJS

I want to use the RequireJS-Facebook Mixin at Github: https://github.com/luan/ember-facebook

I can get it mostly running, requirejs loads ember and the facebook .js file, starts the app and loads the button template, however the facebook javascript sdk doesn't seem to load and I'm not sure why. There is sparse information at the repos, not really anyone replying on irc, and existing examples are very dated.

I've tried comparing similar projects like: https://github.com/MemoRamirez/AngularJS-Facebook-RequireJS - searching Ember forum/docs so I'm trying here:

main.js

```
(function(root){
    require(["config"], function(config){
        requirejs.config(config);
        require(["App", "ember", "ember-facebook"], function(App, Ember){
            var app_name = config.app_name || "App";
            root[app_name] = App = Ember.Application.createWithMixins(App, Em.Facebook);
            [app_name].set('appId', '591709020896302');
            Em.FacebookView = Ember.View.extend({
              defaultTemplate: 'application'
            });
        });
    });
})(this);
```

config.js

```
define({
    app_name: "MyExampleApp", 
    shim : {
        'ember' : {
            deps: ['handlebars', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Ember'
        }
    },
    paths : {
        'App': 'app/main',      
        'models': 'app/models',
        'views': 'app/views',
        'controllers': 'app/controllers',
        'templates': 'app/templates',
        /*libs*/
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery',
        'handlebars': 'libs/handlebars/1.1.2/handlebars',
        'ember': 'libs/ember/1.3.1/ember',
        'ember-facebook': 'libs/ember-facebook',
        /*requirejs-plugins*/
        'text': 'libs/requirejs-plugins/text',
        'hbs': 'libs/requirejs-plugins/hbs',
        'domReady': 'libs/requirejs-plugins/domReady',
        'order': 'libs/requirejs-plugins/order'
    },
    /*hbs plugin options*/
    hbs: {
        disableI18n: true,
        templateExtension: "html"
    }

});
```

ApplicationView.js

```
define([
    "ember",
    "text!templates/applicationTemplate.html"
], function(Ember, applicationTemplate) {

    var ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
        defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile(applicationTemplate)
    });
    return ApplicationView;
});
```

ApplicationController.js

```
define(["ember"], function(Ember){
    var ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();

    return ApplicationController;
});
```

applicationTemplate.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#if MyExampleApp.FBUser}}
  <div>
    <img {{bindAttr src="MyExampleApp.FBUser.picture" alt="MyExampleApp.FBUser.name"}} />
    {{MyExampleApp.FBUser.name}}
    <a href="#" {{action "logout" target="FB"}}>Logout</a>
  </div>
{{else}}
  {{#view Em.FacebookView type="login-button" data-size="xlarge"
                          data-scope="email, offline_access"}}
    Connect
  {{/view}}
{{/if}}
</script>
```

Error console in Firefox:

```
[16:42:18.010] ReferenceError: Ember is not defined @ file:///F:/Users/Richard/Desktop/Emberjs-RequireJS-master/starter-kit/scripts/libs/ember-facebook.js:4
[16:42:18.174] file:///F:/Users/Richard/Desktop/Emberjs-RequireJS-master/starter-kit/scripts/libs/ember/1.3.1/ember.js
[16:42:18.044] not well-formed @ file:///F:/Users/Richard/Desktop/Emberjs-RequireJS-master/starter-kit/scripts/app/templates/applicationTemplate.html:4
[16:42:18.147] Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. @ file:///F:/Users/Richard/Desktop/Emberjs-RequireJS-master/starter-kit/scripts/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js:5375
[16:42:18.168] TypeError: mixin is undefined @ file:///F:/Users/Richard/Desktop/Emberjs-RequireJS-master/starter-kit/scripts/libs/ember/1.3.1/ember.js:7335
[16:42:18.183] Error: assertion failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Undefined] @ file:///F:/Users/Richard/Desktop/Emberjs-RequireJS-master/starter-kit/scripts/libs/ember/1.3.1/ember.js:836
```

Comment: When I don't use createWithMixins the template does load, but using WithMixins it doesn't load.